# Creating/Updating Woocommerce Products Causing Exceeded Maximum Execution Time

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

I am creating a plugin to insert woocommerce products from an API, and everything is working fine for what I need however because there are a lot of products, the script fails after a while. So the script does its job and inserts about 170-180 products but because the script is running for so long it fails because it reaches the maximum execution time. I am looking for a way to make sure the script can install at least 4k-5k products.

I know I can increase the **maximum execution time** but this does not seem to me like a professional method of doing this job, and it means I would have to increase this manually depending on how many products need to be created/updated which seems very wrong and I am sure there must be a much better way to handle things like this, here is my code so far:

```
    public static function bb_products_api_call() 

{

    // Fetch products from API
    $url = 'http://all-products-api-endpoint-here.com';

    $args = [
        'timeout' => 55,
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'XXXXXXXXX'
        )
    ];

    $external_products = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $url, $args ) );
    $products = json_decode( $external_products );

    echo "<div class=\"wrap\">";
        echo "<pre>";
            foreach($products as $key => $product) {
                if( $product->situation > 0 ) {

                    $str = $product->description;
                    $dash = strpos($str, '-');
                    $dashPostion = $dash + 1;

                    $bar = strpos($str, '|');
                    $barPosition = $bar + 1;

                    if($dash && $bar !== false) {

                        $sD = "";
                        $sB = "";

                        $secondDash = strpos($str, '-', $dashPostion);
                        if($secondDash !== false) {
                            //echo "more than 1 - people!\n ";
                            $sD = $secondDash;
                        } 
                        
                        $secondBar = strpos($str, '|', $barPosition);
                        if($secondBar !== false) {
                            //echo "more than 1 | ffs!\n ";
                            $sB = $secondBar;
                        }

                        if($sD == "" && $secondBar == "") {
                            //echo "all good";

                            

                            // getting final product list
                            $inStock[] = array(
                                "productID" => $product->productID, // ID
                                "modelAndColor" => $product->code2, // model and color
                                "name" => $product->subGroupDescription, // product name (title)
                                "description" => $product->longDescription, // product description
                                "sku" => $product->description, // product SKU
                                "color" => $product->classifier1Description, // color
                                "size" => $product->classifier2Description, // size
                                "category" => $product->classifier4Description, // category
                                "subCategory" => $product->classifier6Description, // sub category
                                "regularPrice" => $product->salesPriceDefault, // product price
                                "hasDiscount" => $product->hasDiscount, // 1 for discount, 0 for not on discount
                                "discountPercentage" => $product->discountPercentage, // discount percentage
                                "stock" => $product->situation, // stock
                                
                            );

                            foreach($inStock as $item) {

                                $hash = $item['sku'];
                                $hash = substr( $hash, 0, strpos( $hash, "-" ) );
                                $uniqueArray[$hash] = $item;

                            }

                            $parentProducts = array_values( $uniqueArray );

                            if(!empty( $parentProducts )) {

                                foreach($parentProducts as $product) {



                                    $variable = $product['sku'];
                                    $variable = substr( $variable, 0, strpos( $variable, "-" ) );
                                    

                                    $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $variable );

                                    $product['sku'] = $variable;

                                    if( empty( $product_id ) ) {

                                        $product_id = self::createOrUpdateProduct( $product );

                                    } else {

                                        $product_id = self::createOrUpdateProduct( $product, $product_id ); 
                                        

                                    }


                                }

                            }

                            
                        }
                        

                    }


                }
            }
        //print_r( $inStock );
        print_r( $parentProducts );
        echo "</pre>";
    echo "</div>";

}
```

I did also try adding a for loop and count how many products have been installed and let the script sleep for 2-3 seconds hoping it would maybe reset the max execution time and prevent it from happening like so (no luck on this):

```
                                for($i = 0; $i >= 25; $i++) {

                                    $variable = $product['sku'];
                                    $variable = substr( $variable, 0, strpos( $variable, "-" ) );
                                    

                                    $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $variable );

                                    $product['sku'] = $variable;

                                    if( empty( $product_id ) ) {

                                        // $product_id = self::createOrUpdateProduct( $product );
                                        if( $product_id = self::createOrUpdateProduct( $product ) ) {
                                            $count = $count + 1;
                                        }

                                    } else {

                                        // $product_id = self::createOrUpdateProduct( $product, $product_id );
                                        if( $product_id = self::createOrUpdateProduct( $product, $product_id ) ) {
                                            $count = $count + 1;
                                        }      

                                    }

                                    if( $count >= 25 ) {

                                        sleep(3);
                                        $count = 0;

                                    }

                                }
```

> **Note**: Please dont mind what I am doing to that SKU by extracting a certain part from it and finding only the distinct model numbers and
> then using them for an SKU, that part is working fine.

If anyone has had similar experiences and found a way to successfully implement a script that does not exceed execution time, I would appreciate a lot if you can share a solution, thank you.

Comment: How are you triggering this script? When a user submits a form? Or using [WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/)?

Comment: I submit this as a form in the backend by clicking a button which fetches the data

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1: Send requests for smaller batches using JavaScript

The user visits a page that contains JavaScript that does "Ajax" requests for small parts of the task.

Determine a batch size that is guaranteed to complete before any timeouts. Maybe that's about 50 to 100 products for you? Given it fails at about 170, with some margin.

Now add a REST API endpoint (or WP Ajax) that you can call that will process this amount of products.

Since the bottleneck here is probably not the API call, you could still fetch the whole API response in one go, store it somewhere (`wp_cache_add` for example), and process it in chunks.

You then need some JavaScript on the front end that sends one of these batches, waits for it to complete, then sends another one, ...

##### Pro:

- server has no long running requests
- relatively easy to implement
- easy to visualize processing status on front end

##### Con:

- need to add JavaScript
- processing doesn't complete if user closes browser tab

#### Examples

##### How to turn code into an endpoint?

You should, first of all, split your logic into functions. Currently your code is all inside a single function making it quite inflexible. Let's assume for the example code that you have a function `saveProduct($data)`, and a function `fetchAllFromApi()` that returns you an array of `$data` arrays. For brevity I won't include their implementation, you can pretty much just move the code from the big function inside them with no major changes.

```
$cache_key = 'someAPIsProducts';
$cache_lifetime = 3600; // 1 hour
$batch_size = 50;
$start = $_GET['start']; // Or any other way to accept request params...

$from_cache = wp_cache_get($cache_key);
$data = $from_cache === false ? fetchAllFromApi() : $from_cache;
if ($from_cache === false) {
    // Cache for next time.
    wp_cache_add($cache_key, $data, null, $cache_lifetime);
}

$batch = array_slice($data, $start, $batch_size);
foreach ($batch as $data) {
    saveProduct($data);
}

// Return successful HTTP response.
wp_send_json_success( ... );
```

I'll explain the front end details using WooCommerce's solution.

##### WooCommerce

###### Back end

Here they [register](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-importers.php#L36) an [endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73166832/edit) for executing a batch.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_do_ajax_product_import', array( $this, 'do_ajax_product_import' ) );
```

The exact details of their endpoint are not that important. In your case you can just put a loop in there and make the loop trigger your product save functions for the specified amount of items in a batch, as per the above code.

###### Front end

I'll just include the relevant fragments from their [front end file handling the import batching](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-production/blob/4dcc47faae2000c0f7a99e364ec34c00232e11cf/assets/js/admin/wc-product-import.js#L35).

They initiate a request to this endpoint in the `run_import` method.

```
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action          : 'woocommerce_do_ajax_product_import',
            position        : $this.position,
            mapping         : $this.mapping,
            file            : $this.file,
            update_existing : $this.update_existing,
            delimiter       : $this.delimiter,
            security        : $this.security
        },
```

In the [response handler](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-production/blob/4dcc47faae2000c0f7a99e364ec34c00232e11cf/assets/js/admin/wc-product-import.js#L60-L75) the function calls itself as long as the response didn't indicate this was the last batch.

```
if ( 'done' === response.data.position ) {
    // ... 
} else {
    $this.run_import();
}
```

And that's basically it. Their implementation is a bit more complex because they handle mapping CSV fields, which you don't need to do.

##### ElasticPress plugin

*If you don't have this plugin set up (and it requires setting up ES too), it can be a bit hard to follow the code. Still mentioning it because in case you do have it, it's easy to see their solution in action on the admin index page.*

This plugin provides integration for WordPress with ElasticSearch. While it's quite a different use case, they have the same problem when trying to synchronize a large amount of data to the ElasticSearch database.

###### Front end

They use essentially the React version of WooCommerce's jQuery code. [source](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress/blob/develop/assets/js/sync/index.js#L274-L302)

```
const doIndex = useCallback(
    /**
     * Start or continues a sync.
     *
     * @param {boolean} isDeleting Whether to delete and sync.
     * @returns {void}
     */
    (isDeleting) => {
        index(isDeleting)
            .then(updateSyncState)
            .then(
                /**
                 * If an existing sync has been found just check its status,
                 * otherwise continue syncing.
                 *
                 * @param {string} method Sync method.
                 */
                (method) => {
                    if (method === 'cli') {
                        doIndexStatus();
                    } else {
                        doIndex(isDeleting);
                    }
                },
            )
            .catch(syncFailed);
    },
    [doIndexStatus, index, syncFailed, updateSyncState],
);
```

###### Back end

I didn't find time to locate this file, but they work similarly to WooCommerce.

### Approach 2: Asynchronous server side processing

You could set up an offline job runner of some sort, that has a really long max execution time. Then when the user requests to get products from the API, you can immediately send a response notifying the job is accepted for processing.

A user can then track on your page the status of this processing job (or multiple).

You can use [WP-Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) as a "poor man's cron job", which will execute these jobs on random requests. But it's not advisable, definitely if the job takes long to run.

At least that's the default behavior. You can set it up to [only run when triggered by the system cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/).

You could still batch theses jobs of course.

##### Pro:

- doesn't need web requests so will always complete
- no impact on web traffic response times

##### Con:

- requires much more complex infrastructure
- challenging to implement

### Approach 3: Run batch SQL queries to improve capacity

*This approach is generally not advisable in WordPress, as it bypasses a whole bunch of filters and actions that may be used by other plugins. For some types of data it's not a problem, but you should only do this if you're entirely sure it's safe.*

The slowness is likely due to many separate database queries being executed for every product, one by one.

If you know the exact structure your data needs to have in the database, and are sure it doesn't need to pass through any filters first, you can write plain SQL queries that do batched inserts.

There's also [this WordPress StackExchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9634/194324) which suggests to use `wp_defer_term_counting( true )` before batch importing. I just mention it here because likely it won't be enough of a speedup for you, but you never know.

##### Pro:

- orders of magnitude faster

##### Con:

- generally unsafe to do
- need to maintain a complex SQL query

### Approach 4: Use [WooCommerce's built in CSV importer](https://woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/)

WooCommerce has a built in CSV importer which already handles importing large amounts of items. It's implemented like approach 1, here's the [endpoint they call from the front end to execute batches](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-importers.php#L202-L304).

This involves writing the API data to a CSV file, and inserting the right records to initiate the WooCommerce import as though a user had just uploaded that file. Alternatively you could figure out how to directly create these import jobs without needing the intermediary file. With the file is probably overall easier to implement, though.

*I might come back to this with more detailed steps, as it would definitely be the overall best solution.*

##### Pro:

- no need to implement these features
- more stable

##### Con:

- need to figure out how WooCommerce CSV upload works
- may require a lot of "wiring up" code

Comment: Hi there, I understand the possibilities but I need help in actual code on this one

Comment: What is your approach then? Which piece of the code are you missing?

Comment: Your original question takes another approach: try to do it all in 1 request. I didn't mention the approach as an option because it's always going to be too slow. Even if you increase the timeout, it's too slow for UX. You'll have to make broader changes, to code that was not posted in your question, so it's hard to go into detail about how that would look for you, or even which approach works best.

Comment: can you provide code for Approach 1 or 2?

Comment: I added some examples for approach 1 (batching from JS). If it's a plugin, approach 2 (sort of cron) is probably too tricky for users to set up. For your case approach 1 seems a lot better.